# how can I run my powershell script in line?

Tags: powershell, syntax, command-line-interface

I want to execute powershell inline , but when I try to execute everything. I got `Out-Null : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'do'.`

```
$OutputString = 'Hello World'
$WScript = New-Object -ComObject 'wscript.shell'
$WScript.Run('notepad.exe') | Out-Null
do {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }
until ($WScript.AppActivate('notepad'))
$WScript.SendKeys($OutputString)
```

inline powershell

```
 powershell -Command $OutputString = 'Hello World';$WScript = New-Object -ComObject 'wscript.shell';$WScript.Run('notepad.exe') | Out-Null ;do{ Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100};until($WScript.AppActivate('notepad'));$WScript.SendKeys($OutputString);
```

I want to get the same result inline , but I got this issue

Comment: There is a `;` before `until` which should not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had 3 problems:

- a missing `;` before the `do` statement (multiple statements placed on a single line must be `;`-separated in PowerShell)

  - you've later added that, which makes your command inconsistent with the described symptom.
- a missing `until` keyword after `do { ... }`

  - you've later added that, but with a preceding `;`, which breaks the `do` statement.
- unescaped use of `|`, which means that `cmd.exe` itself interpreted it, not PowerShell as intended (I'm assuming you're calling this from `cmd.exe`, otherwise there'd be no need to call PowerShell's CLI via `powershell.exe`).

  - `|` must be escaped as `^|` to make `cmd.exe` pass it through to PowerShell.

Fixing these problems yields the following command for use **from `cmd.exe`**:

```
# From cmd.exe / a batch file:
powershell -Command $OutputString = 'Hello World'; $WScript = New-Object -ComObject 'wscript.shell'; $WScript.Run('notepad.exe') ^| Out-Null; do{ Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100} until ($WScript.AppActivate('notepad')); $WScript.SendKeys($OutputString)
```

---

If you do want to run your code **from PowerShell**, you can just invoke it *directly*, as shown in the first snippet in your question - there's no need to create *another* PowerShell process via `powershell.exe`

If, for some reason, you do need to create another PowerShell process, use the script-block syntax (`{ ... }`) to pass the command, in which case no escaping is needed:

```
# From PowerShell
powershell -Command { $OutputString = 'Hello World'; $WScript = New-Object -ComObject 'wscript.shell'; $WScript.Run('notepad.exe') | Out-Null; do{ Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100} until ($WScript.AppActivate('notepad')); $WScript.SendKeys($OutputString) }
```